# How to find a Bluetooth device's manufacturer

Tags: windows, windows-registry, bluetooth, wmi

I am trying to get the Manufacturer information for any given Bluetooth device, such as this mouse:

[image]

I have tried WMI, and the best I got was "Microsoft"
I've searched through the registry, and the best I found was a ManufacturerId of 0xA (10), which when I changed, didn't seem to affect anything.

To make things weirder, pairing the same device shown on a different computer will have that field be `Unavailable`, like the Description field is.

Note, it's not just this device I'm interested in. I want to be able to get the manufacturer for *any* Bluetooth device, whether it be a mouse, keyboard, headset, or thermometer.

Any idea how I can get that information? Whether it be the real name, or "Unavailable".

Comment: A simple Internet search found the [manufacturer's site](http://madcatz.com/gamesmart-m-o-u-s-9/) easily. If that is not what you are looking for, please [edit] your question to be specific about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @CharlieRB I'm trying to get the string "Mad Catz" (for this specific instance), or the string which is the manufacturer for any Bluetooth device. I've added details to hopefully make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

One way to determine the manufacturer would be to use the MAC address it uses for communication. Mad Catz is assigned `00:15:9E:00:00:00 - 00:15:9E:FF:FF:FF` You could pull that via WMI and compare against a database of known ranges for vendors.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't help with the case when it's `Unavailable`.